# Number of request to an elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any elastic search way to count number of request to an elastic search index.
I have a search in my website uses elastic search. I want to find how many times search is happened each day.

Answer (score 0):

`GET /_stats/search?index=my_index&filter_path=indices`